# Return a count of all foreign keys across all tables in database without a cursor - in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found someone asking the exact question I have, except the question and answers appear to be specific to SQL Server, even though that fact was ommited.

Here's the question [Return a count of all foreign keys across all tables in database without a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28729215/1402498)

And what looks to be an elegant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729413/1402498

But I need to do this in Postgres. Is there an elegant way to accomplish the same thing in Postgres?

Comment: I think the answers here might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation *in the question*.  Link-only questions are frowned upon.